# Disabling logging in PySpark? I've already gone through other posts as well

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've tried modifying the log4j file in the conf folder, but after I do that I get the error when I run my file

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.CosnsoleAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.CosnsoleAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
```

This happened specifically when I changed the log4j.properties.template file to log4j.properties.

I also did

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

but then I still get log output.

```
INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to:
INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `org.apache.log4j.CosnsoleAppender`, should be `ConsoleAppender`.

Comment: Always love the simple solutions.